# How access data in MongoLab with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I'm trying to connect to my online database that is allocated in MongoLab.

I have already connected to the database with the following code:

(To protect myself I changed some data)

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var database = {
    url: "3ouojekljs8.mongolab.com:i398948",
    name: "mydatabase-database",
    user: "myusername",
    password: "mypassword",
};

var loginCredentials = database.user + ":" + database.password;

    var db = mongoose;

db.connect("mongodb://" + loginCredentials + "@" + database.url + "/" + database.name);


db.connection.on("open", function() {
    console.log("connection to database done!");
});

db.connection.on("error", function() {
    console.log("error");
});
```

I'm already connect, now i need pull the data from the bookings collection,

![enter image description here][1]

I was trying like this:

```
mongoose.model('Bookings', new Schema({
        date: String,
        event: String,
        name: String,
        phone: String,
        email: String,
        obs: String
    }),
    'bookings'
);
```

But in the console, the following message appears:

```
  ReferenceError: Schema is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define Schema: `var Schema = mongoose.Schema;`

Example of querying data.

```
var util = require('util');
var async = require('async');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://myusername:mypassword@3ouojekljs8.mongolab.com:398948/mydatabase-database');

var bookingSchema = {
  date: String,
  event: String,
  name: String,
  phone: String,
  email: String,
  obs: String
};

var Booking = mongoose.model('Booking', bookingSchema);

Booking.find({}, function(err, bookings) {
    async.each(bookings, booking, function(booking, next) {
        console.log(util.format('%s: %s', booking.name, booking.phone));
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('done reading records');
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks very much! i was searching in the mongoose documentation but did not find anything. Do you know how can i see this data in my terminal?.. For example, if i want see my phones..

Comment: Thanks very much @Timothy. U are awesome <3.